# Umbraco Architecture with query string parameters for document

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco4

I have a client web app that I've been asked to make some updates to. I have a small number of development hours to work within so a redesign of the system is not an option at this time.

The app was written using classic asp with logic to pull certain content dynamically from a custom database and to write back certain user actions to the same custom database. There is an admin area for viewing these logged user actions.

At some point in time portions of the web app were migrated to use Umbraco 4 for the cms. I've been tasked with migrating some additional content, that is still being pulled from the original custom database, into the context of the CMS.

The content in question is structured so that the content node's document type points to a special masterpage. The master page has codebehind logic that checks for a query string parameter and uses that parameter to query the database for content specific to that parameter. In then populates one specific section on the page with that content.

The logic also uses the query string parameter when writing user actions back to the custom database.

I need to maintain the url syntax and behavior of writing user actions back to the custom database but move the displayed content specific to that parameter into the CMS somewhere. Where should I place this content in the CMS and how can I access it from those pages via the query string parameter?

Url Examples:

```
/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/
/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/?partner=partner1
/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/?partner=partner2

/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/Review/
/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/Review/?partner=partner1
/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/Review/?partner=partner2

/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/Checkout/
/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/Checkout/?partner=partner1
/site_home/Node1/Node2/Node3/Checkout/?partner=partner2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide a bit clearer explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, I am sure that I can assist you further.  However, the code below and link to the discussion from which I pulled it may help get you on the path.  Give me some feedback or edit your question and I will edit my answer to assist.

```
@{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["query"]))
   {
     int result= 0;
        if(Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["query"].ToString(), out result))
       {
         umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode node = new umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode(result);

           <h1> @node.Name </h1>
     }
     else 
     {
         <h2>No query found</h2>
       }
 }

}
```

[Umbraco Forums - Render Node content from querystring](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/39655-Render-Node-content-from-querystring?p=1)